# Unable to run databricks notebook from another notebook with dbutils.notebook.run("mynotebook", 3600)

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

When I attempt run a notebook from another databricks notebook with the dbutils.notebook.run("mynotebook", 3600) I get the error:

```
com.databricks.WorkflowException: com.databricks.NotebookExecutionException: FAILED: Unable to access the notebook &#34;/Users/xxxxxxxx@xxxxx.co.uk/path/mynotebooks&#34;. Either it does not exist, or the identity used to run this job, xxxxxx (xxxxx@xxxxx.co.uk), lacks the required permissions.
```

However, I can successfully run the notebook using the following:

%run "/path/mynotebook"

Can someone let me know why I'm getting the error suggesting I don't have the permissions to execute the notebook with dbutils.notebook.run("mynotebook", 3600)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the below approach:

```
dbutils.notebook.run("./child", 3600)
```

[image]

This function will execute the specified notebook (**child**) in a new notebook context, allowing you to run code in the child notebook independently from the parent notebook.

**Child Notebook:**

```
child_variable =  "this is child variable"
dbutils.notebook.exit(child_variable)
```

```
  Notebook exited: this is child variable
```

The `dbutils.notebook` function syntax is as follows:

```
dbutils.notebook.run(notebookpath, timeout_in_seconds, parameters)
```

The dbutils.notebook function takes three arguments:

**Notebook_path:** The path of the target notebook to be executed.

**Timeout_in_seconds:** The maximum time in seconds the notebook is allowed to run before throwing an exception.

**parameters:** A JSON-formatted string used to send parameters to the child notebook. Parameters should be specified as key-value pairs, e.g., {'parameter1': 'value1', 'parameter2': 'value2'}.

**Reference:** [Call a notebook from another notebook in Databricks](https://azureops.org/articles/call-a-notebook-from-another-notebook-in-databricks/)